# How to apply torchvision transformations to zip file

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, torchvision

I was trying to download CelebA data set and apply transformation to it via code:

```
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.datasets import CelebA

celeba_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.CenterCrop(140),
    transforms.Resize([64, 64]),
    transforms.ToTensor()
    ])
CelebA(root='path',
       split='train',
       download=True,
       transform=celeba_transforms)
```

However I obtained error: `BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`. I did some research about this error and it seems that its quite popular and not easy to solve (since the problem is with Google Drive which has a daily maximum quota for any file, which seems to be exceeded for the CelebA files).

My solution then was to simply download file from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/celeba-dataset) in zip. However then I have plain non-transformed CelebA data.

Is there any possibility to still apply `celeba_transforms` to this data?

**EDIT**

```
CelebA(root='archive_celeba.zip',
       split='train',
       download=False,
       transform=celeba_transforms)
```

I obtained error:

```
RuntimeError: Dataset not found or corrupted. You can use download=True to download it
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation from [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/datasets.html#celeba):

> download (bool, optional) – If true, downloads the dataset from the internet and puts it in root directory. If dataset is already downloaded, it is not downloaded again.

you can set download to false and then it will still perform the transformations on the local dataset.

Comment: Hi DNy! It is better if you can quote the relevant part of the documentation instead of posting the link. So that your answer stays relevant in the future even if something happens with the link that you're quoting. Please consider doing this.